# Trouble with GData API while using "DocumentListEntry.updateMedia()" method

Tags: java, gdata

I'm using the updateMedia(boolean) method of DocumentListEntry from GData API. 
Sometimes this command worked, but in the most times an exception is threw.

The code (documentList is an DocumentListEntry object):

```
public void flush() throws IOException {
    try {
        if(((ByteArrayOutputStream)os).size()>0){
            documentList.setMediaSource(
                    new MediaByteArraySource(((ByteArrayOutputStream)os).toByteArray(), mimeType));
            documentList.updateMedia(true);
            ((ByteArrayOutputStream)os).reset();
        }
    } catch (ServiceException ex) {
        throw new IOException(ex);
    }
}
```

The command "documentList.updateMedia(true);" throw's this exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils.invokeMethod(MethodUtils.java:216)
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils.invokeMethod(MethodUtils.java:162)
        at com.ralph.agente.Agent.run(Agent.java:191)
        at com.ralph.agente.Agent.run(Agent.java:134)
        at company.google.conexao.RecebeObjetoThread.geraSinaisVitaisAgent(RecebeObjetoThread.java:61)
        at company.google.conexao.RecebeObjetoThread.run(RecebeObjetoThread.java:133)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Unexpected resource version ID
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>invalidResourceVersion</code><internalReason>Unexpected resource version ID</internalReason></error></errors>

        at com.company.google.io.GoogleDocsOutputStream.flush(GoogleDocsOutputStream.java:142)
        at com.company.google.io.GoogleDocsOutputStream.close(GoogleDocsOutputStream.java:148)
        at br.edu.company.google.processo.GeraSinaisVitaisAgent.bodyAgent(GeraSinaisVitaisAgent.java:133)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Unexpected resource version ID
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>invalidResourceVersion</code><internalReason>Unexpected resource version ID</internalReason></error></errors>

        at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:594)
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:563)
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:552)
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:530)
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:535)
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.update(Service.java:1563)
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.update(Service.java:1530)
        at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.update(GoogleService.java:583)
        at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.update(MediaService.java:484)
        at com.company.google.io.GoogleDocsOutputStream.flush(GoogleDocsOutputStream.java:137)
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Correcttion

The correct StackTrace was this:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that was missing the command "documentList.setETag(String)". Then I set an '*' character, and it works!

Reference: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/issues/detail?id=250#c0